# ASP.NET MVC 4 Session expiration

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I detect session expiration with:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (null != filterContext.HttpContext.Session)
    {
        // Check if we have a new session
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            // Check if session has timed out
            if ((null != cookie) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "SessionExpired");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Error");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("timeout", "true");

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
                return;
            }
        }
        else { //continue with action as usual
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time I run the application, the `SessionExpired` action is fired (it finds the `ASP.NET_SessionId` string in the cookie when I request the application url for the first time), then when I load another url the application works OK. How to fix that?

Comment: What would you like it to do in the case the session eventually expires?

Comment: Redirect to SessionExpired action of the Error controller.

Comment: Is it really an error if the session expires? Wouldn't you want your user to get a new session (via re-auth)? I think you have the chicken or egg problem going on.

Comment: The requirement is to display a page that says: "Your session has expired".

Comment: Could you check how long the sessionId has been expired in the database? It sounds like maybe you only want to redirect to the session expired page if it's expired and less than X hours old

Comment: @AndrewWalters How can I check that? What is the relation between the http session and the DB? I don't understand.

Comment: If you store session state in the database you could query it to find when a session started. If it's not in the sessions table it would be cleaned up already and pretty old. 

If you don't use database for sessions you could create a variable with the start time in the session start event. Something like the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425183/how-to-get-the-remaining-session-timeout-using-sessionstate